# Character to Integer Ada

Tags: ada

I'm trying to turn characters into integers in Ada, nothing seems to work, I've so far been able for it to return DEC from ASCII but I would like to return 0 (Integer).

> Character'Pos('0');

returns 48 --I want it to return 0?

Comment: `48` is the ascii value of `0`. It's safe to subtract 48. `49` is the ascii value of `1`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch ... but it would definitely not be the proper way to do it.  You would loose the check if the character is actually a digit (unless the target type only includes the range `0 .. 9`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't convert characters directly to the integer value they represent, but it is possible to do with strings:

```
   Some_Integer_Variable := Some_Integer_Type'Value ("0");
```

Or if you have a character variable:

```
   Some_Integer_Variable := Some_Integer_Type'Value ((1 => Character_Variable));
```

Comment: Does the conversion from character to string add some overhead?

Comment: That depends.  It may add two integers to the memory foot-print in some cases.